# MVC 4 and Windows Forms

Tags: c#

i just wanted to ask, is it possible that my mvc4 would be able to read a textbox from my windows form application?

it goes this way,
1. windows forms application has a textbox and submit button
2. I input a value on the text box and press the submit button
3. the mvc 4 application gets the data and displays it on a text box

is this even possible?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are running a WinForms application on a web server?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, my WinForms run only the desktop, and my MVC4 runs on just the locahost, they are both running at the same time as i want the data to be transferred.

Comment: Generally, if you have a web app, then it's best to use web services (like [Anuraj](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18507822/69809) wrote below). That way you can move your web app to a third party server and have everything work the same way.

Comment: not familiar with the webservice yet, but ill read some on that topic, what methods are you saying that could make it faster?

Comment: I started writing but realized it doesn't make much sense for your problem. You would only see benefits for larger amounts of data and I am not sure if this approach would be justified at all (given the coupling you would introduce). My advice is to [forget about performance](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) until you actually have a working version and have concrete evidence that the speed is not satisfactory.

Comment: ok, so i guess webservice is my solution for now, thanks ill start to read about webservice

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, you can do a HTTP Post to a controller action or to a View using HTTPWebRequest class.

Comment: not quite familiar with the webservice,ill read some regarding this webservice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it (although i expect there are far simpler ways) Is in your MVC app have an event listner set up to listen to a database. You can then update this database form your winforms app with the relevant information and have your event listener respond to it. You would most likely want to use some AJAX in your MVC app to make it asynchronous.

Comment: i see thanks!, i think i better have to study more on mvc 4 there's a lot i have not known yet, like the event listener,. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. By using WebRequest from Your Form Application Like the following example. It is from VB.NET Application. Requesting data to the Webserver. I hope you understand, and try to create one for yourself.

```
Public Function SENDSMS(ByVal finsysid As Integer, ByVal smsto As String, ByVal msg As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    SENDSMS = False
    Dim request As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.infodev.com/sms/sms4digit.php")
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim postData As String
    postData = "finsysid=" & finsysid & "&to=" & smsto & "&msg=" & msg
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()
    SENDSMS = True
    'Return (responseFromServer)

    Error_Desc = Replace(responseFromServer, "'", "-")
    SENDSMS = InStr(responseFromServer, "success", CompareMethod.Text)

    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox(Err.Description, , Err.Number)
    Exit Function
    Resume
End Function
```